# Read specific date log from rails production application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ubuntu

I have tried tail -f log/production.log and grep history, but I need specific commends how I can get those log.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First you need the controller action name which you want to find.

This will print all logs from specific controller action.

**Get only last line of a log:**  grep "Processing by OrdersController#create" log/production.log -B 1

Then copy from the last log output with date.

**Get 50 lines after error:**
grep "Started POST \"/orders\" for 68.107.123.159 at 2015-02-18 " log/production.log -A 50

This will print 50 lines after the grep output.

Comment: how can i select the last "Started POST \"/orders\" for 68.107.123.159 at 2015-02-18"